# Passing Http parameters in php shows "Authentication parameter missing"

Tags: php, http, curl, https, header

I want to send the app id and app key with the request to get a reply as json .But the response is always 'authentication parameters missing. i don't know what i am missing.i am a newbie in php too

```
<?php

$data = array('app_id'=>'123',
          'app_key'=>'123',
'Accept'=>'application/json');
 $query=http_build_query($data);
 $language='en';
     $url="https://odapi.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/".$language.'/'.'ace';
$curl=curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($data)); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  $x=curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
 ?>
```

help please guys

Comment: `http_build_query()` is for the data, not for the headers. I'm guessing that `app_key` and `app_id` is header values, since you added `Accept` (which _definitely_ a header) in the same array? Your code is currently setting them as post data, not headers.

Comment: rather than post your credentials, try setting them in your request headers. `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$data)`

Comment: using curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$data) returns nothing but the autentication error is gone

Comment: I'm sure something returns, but it does't look like you're doing much with it.

Comment: I tried to print the result nothing gets printed